# Inquiry on UiPath's logging framework - concerns on Log4Shell vulnerability

Tags: security, log4j, uipath

I wish to inquire if there is any concern from UiPath in regards to the threat posed by the Apache Log4j vulnerability (https://amp.theguardian.com/technology/2021/dec/10/software-flaw-most-critical-vulnerability-log-4-shell). I know UiPath orchestrator runs on MS IIS and wanted to know what logging framework is used.

Answer (score 2):

regarding [this post in the UiPath forum](https://forum.uipath.com/t/inquiry-on-uipaths-logging-framework-concerns-on-log4shell-vulnerability/369178/4) Robots and Orchstrator are using NLog, which is a different framework.

Also it is mentioned that UiPath Insight is using Log4j. They are currently evaluating the impact. [See here](https://forum.uipath.com/t/log4j-critical-vulnerability/369229/6)